# Why I cannot print "first"?

Tags: c++, printing, linked-list, operator-overloading

I used linked list to store my data. The constructor and print function seem to be fine, I just don't know whether my pointer gone wrong.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>   
using namespace std;

///constructor
String::String( const char * s): head(NULL)
{
    ListNode * h = head;
    h = new ListNode(s[0], NULL);
    ListNode * c = h;
    for(int i = 1; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        c->next = new ListNode(s[i], NULL);
        c = c->next;
    }
}
// redefine the << operator
ostream & operator << ( ostream & out, String str )
{
    str.print(out);
    return out;
}
istream & operator >> ( istream & in, String & str )
{
    str.read(in);
    return in;
}
void String::print( ostream & out )
{
    ListNode * c = head;
    for(; c != '\0'; c = c->next)
        {out << c->info;}
}
void String::read( istream & in )
{
    ListNode * c = head;
    for(; c != '\0'; c = c->next)
        in >> c->info;
}
int main()
{
    cout << "123" << endl;
    String firstString("First");
    cout << firstString << endl;
    cout << "1234" << endl;
    cout << "12345" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And my result is

```
123

1234
12345
```

It's wired that my 123 and 1234 12345 can be printed out, but my "first" disappears.

Comment: It might be helpful to see the definition of your classes and the list node

Comment: @kcraigie Appreciate your time anyway. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your constructor.  You initialize `head` to null, copy the value of `head` to `h` (NULL in this case), assign `h` to point to a new `ListNode` but never reassign the `head` pointer to the `ListNode` pointed to by `h`.

```
String::String( const char * s): head(NULL)
{
    head = new ListNode(s[0], NULL);
    ListNode * c = head;
    for(int i = 1; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        c->next = new ListNode(s[i], NULL);
        c = c->next;
    }
}
```